# Lib Panorama Spherical for Android

Tags: java, android, image, 360-degrees

I trying to search for a lib to open Spherical images on my app android but the only one I found is the panoramaGL.

I tried to use but using the jar I had an error and using the panoramaGL project I had gradle problems.

Just to know the error using the jar is this one

```
Couldn't load glues from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/xxx.xxx.xxxxxxx.torresinglaterra-7.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/xxx.xxx.xxxxxxx.torresinglaterra-7]: findLibrary returned null
```

So I'm trying to find another lib.

Someone recommend or know of any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add pre built *.so files in Android Studio using gradle 0.7.2+. First create the jniLibs at this location /app/src/main/ location and copy the all the folder with *.so files (armeabi, armeabi-v7a, mips, x86) in the jniLibs.